# Shopify: Update metafields when certain price & compare at price are set?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am working on a Shopify theme built by another developer. Originally, when we would update the "Compare at Price" and "Price" when editing a product, a custom metafield called "details.final_sale" would be updated to "true" or "false" depending on the percentage of the sale.  If the metafield was "true", a "Final Sale" message would display on that product's page. Otherwise, the default would be "false" for that field so that the message would not display.

For example, if we had a product that had a price of $40 and compare at price at $100, it would be 60% off. The "details.final_sale" metafield is supposed to update to true for any products that are above 60%, but now it doesn't seem to be working.

Can anyone steer me in the direction of where I should look to automatically update the metafield when a certain discount percentage is set? Again, it originally was set to function this way but all of sudden it stopped working...

Comment: David's looks like the right answer to me. I've just responded to  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41643795/ with something that might be a usable workaround for you.

Comment: You would only be able to update a variable not a metafield.

Answer (score 2):

You either did that magic manually or with some scripting. If you see no custom Apps installed in your shop, then there is almost no chance that metafield was set except for it being done manually. If it was a custom App, then it is no longer working, so contact the developer.